# How to fix No module named modules.BigQueryHandler error in an web.py service?

Tags: python, web.py

I have developed a web service using Python. The project structure goes as follows:

[image]

It runs perfectly on local machine, but when I deployed to server and tried to run the `LogicImplementer.py`, it returns an error:

> No module named modules.BigQueryHandler

Here is the code for `LogicImplementer`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("...")
import modules.BigQueryHandler as BQ
import scripts.DigINCacheEngine.CacheController as CC
import web
```

I have added `__init__.py` to each and every directory that gets imported.

Comment: it seems like the path to module not in python sys.path so that import error is raised. according to your file struture, try to change sys.path.append("...")  to sys.path.append(__file__.rsplit(os.path.sep, 3)[0])  :-)

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'file' has no attribute 'rsplit'

Comment: it is underline underline file underline underline ,  it becomes bold 'file' in comments, like the init.py  in your post.

Comment: it did not work either

Comment: @LFJ To stop underscores `_` and asterisks `*` being interpreted as style commands you should use backticks around code in comments (and for code in questions or answers outside code blocks).

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you post it as a comment

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're asking what a backtick is, then it's a `\`` and on normal keyboards it's just under the `Esc` key.

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you post the line as a comment or answer. sorry still am not getting what you have asked to do

Comment: LFJ suggested that you try this: `sys.path.append(__file__.rsplit(os.path.sep, 3)[0])` but the underscores got lost because they got interpreted as __bold__ style commands.

Comment: i have already tried that and it dint work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93809/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-pm-2ring).

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to solve your problem - I was only offering help on how to put code into comments.